Is it possible to achieve synchronization between main and child processes while using Boost Shared Memory?
I am trying to achieve a functionality that I have to maintain a Global Database, let's say a map of string object and an unique id. I have to spawn multiple process to gather the data. I decide on using queue in the shared memory for inter-process communication, between the spawned processes and the main process, so that the spawned processes can dump the data they collect in the queue and main process populates the Global Database.
How can I achieve the read write synchronization between child processes and main process while reading and writing in the shared memory?
